# ssh-agent keeps asking for password

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, ssh-agent

I am trying to use ssh-agent to not have to type in my password every time I use an SSH key. I am following the instructions / guides but I still am asked every time for the password - how is this possible?

```
svarto@Svarto-Desktop:~$ ssh-agent bash
svarto@Svarto-Desktop:~$ ssh-add -l

The agent has no identities.

svarto@Svarto-Desktop:~$ ssh-add /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa 

Enter passphrase for /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa: 
Identity added: /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa (/home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa)

svarto@Svarto-Desktop:~$ ssh bitwarden 

Enter passphrase for key '/home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa':
```

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and I type the above in the same terminal, and even though the ssh-add says the identity is added as soon as I try to connect and use that key I am asked for the passphrase again. Hope someone can help...

EDIT:

```
svarto@Svarto-Desktop:~$ ssh -vvv bitwarden
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/svarto/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/svarto/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/svarto/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for bitwarden
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 172.16.10.99 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.10.99 [172.16.10.99] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 172.16.10.99:22 as 'svarto'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/svarto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/svarto/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.16.10.99
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:W5Kb77iOUZUhzyO2Rmr9tNXXGRea4NZirWLCp8oskJU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/svarto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/svarto/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.16.10.99
debug1: Host '172.16.10.99' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/svarto/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa
```

Comment: Please, post the debug log from your connection: `ssh -vvv bitwarden`. Also do not use DSA keys. They are inherently insecure.

Comment: @Jakuje thanks for responding. I added the debug log as requested. Thanks for raising my awareness about DSA keys, I will update.

Comment: Do you have access to server logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have separate public key stored in `/home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa.pub` for OpenSSH to be able to pair the key in agent with the key in configuration. You can generate it using the `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa > /home/svarto/.ssh/bitwarden_dsa.pub
```